# ajax calls not showing any content in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, wget

I am trying to crawl artist urls from this page

```
https://myspace.com/discover/artists?genreId=1002532
```

But this page is making ajax call to get user deatils.I could see this url in firebug

```
https://myspace.com/ajax/artistspage?chartType=heavyrotation&genreId=1002532&page=0
```

If i open this url in seperate tab there is no content displayed but if i view it response tab in firebug it is showing all the deatils.

How could i get all the contents?

Comment: it's simple, the server respond HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Comment: @xzegga How could i make it work?

Comment: I am not expert in authentication but I think that this It's not possible, you need to authenticate to use this service, and you don't have a proper credential, token or cookie to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the request in firebug for https://myspace.com/ajax/artistspage?chartType=heavyrotation&genreId=1002532&page=0 when you try to go to it manually in the browser you will notice that it gets a `401 Unauthorized` response. This is because the request headers are set in a special way when being requested from the official myspace page https://myspace.com/discover/artists?genreId=1002532 that makes the request for the data valid. These headers are not present when your browser requests the data.

Here is the valid headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Client:persistentId=53065c06-c877-47c5-933a-4b22d7f28cd9&screenWidth=1440&screenHeight=900&timeZoneOffsetHours=7&visitId=31c9d922-9984-4ac5-9bb0-0bb253bc89c3&windowWidth=1043&windowHeight=407
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:persistent_id=pid%3D53065c06-c877-47c5-933a-4b22d7f28cd9%26llid%3D%26lprid%3D%26lltime%3D; beacons_enabled=true; __utmt=1; ads=adInitVisit%3D1432446031357; player=sequenceId%3D-1%26paused%3Dtrue%26currentTime%3D0%26volume%3D0.5%26mute%3Dfalse%26shuffled%3Dfalse%26repeat%3Doff%26mode%3Dqueue%26radioEntity%3D%26radioMediaType%3D%26radioMediaId%3D%26radioCurrentTime%3D0%26pinned%3Dfalse%26streamStartDateTime%3D%26radioStreamStartDateTime%3D%26at%3D360%26incognito%3Dfalse%26allowSkips%3Dtrue%26ccOn%3Dfalse; visit_id=31c9d922-9984-4ac5-9bb0-0bb253bc89c3; __utma=102911388.1051160901.1432446029.1432446029.1432446029.1; __utmb=102911388.2.10.1432446029; __utmc=102911388; __utmz=102911388.1432446029.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
DNT:1
Hash:NjI2YWM0YzM0YmJiZTg1NsKqwpMGw4HCuAvClMOGwoxAXMOXw50Qw5PCnH7DqVQIAygsY25wwrfCtsOcd8KuwqnCiMKSwobCrMKswpvDhEIrDcKYM0rCocKbJcKYEsKWw53Dr8KIwq7CgMKWw5XCo8KBGHVvURQKwpzDrMO9w5fDlsKzNhDChMOtw7wgw7NuDsK0wq1oC1sOOXAzK8KuwqdyEUDDnRk+w6BPwrIhfsKtw7Fewrcpa8Okw4c%3D
Host:myspace.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://myspace.com/discover/artists?genreId=1002532
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2409.0 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

And here are the invalid ones:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:persistent_id=pid%3D53065c06-c877-47c5-933a-4b22d7f28cd9%26llid%3D%26lprid%3D%26lltime%3D; beacons_enabled=true; __utmt=1; ads=adInitVisit%3D1432446031357; __utma=102911388.1051160901.1432446029.1432446029.1432446029.1; __utmb=102911388.2.10.1432446029; __utmc=102911388; __utmz=102911388.1432446029.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); player=sequenceId=-1&paused=true&currentTime=0&volume=0.5&mute=false&shuffled=false&repeat=off&mode=queue&radioCurrentTime=0&pinned=false&at=360&incognito=false&allowSkips=true&ccOn=false; visit_id=31c9d922-9984-4ac5-9bb0-0bb253bc89c3
DNT:1
Host:myspace.com
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2409.0 Safari/537.36
```

You'll notice that there are a couple differences, the most significant being that the valid request headers include a `Hash`, as well as a `Referer` header. I assume at least the Hash must be present to be verified by the server. You would have to find out how this Hash is generated on the myspace page, and probably also set the `Referer` tag to fake the request being from the proper page.

If you dig into the JS found on the page you will find this snippet located in https://x.myspacecdn.com/new/common/js/global.7A07230F0926F7451E2F85D8F2C647D0.min.js

`a.setRequestHeader("Hash",context.hashMashter)`

This is where the Hash header is set, using context.hashMashter, which if you go to https://x.myspacecdn.com/new/common/js/authentication.68B094D880713CC3A9EB77F984FC09F4.min.js you can see is set with this snippet:

`context.hashMashter=a.hashMashter`

I don't know what `a` is yet, but if you want to continue exploring, I think this is a good start.